# I Have Problem Rigging This Arm

Tags: animation, rigging

I'm rigging this FPS arm and I wanted it to have a wrist rotation rig (small bone on the wrist) that works great but when I bend the elbow this happens...
I think it's because Blender isn't considering the big forearm bone which is the parent of the wrist and for some reason it is moving the mesh based on the hand (not IK) weight paint.(Hierarchy goes like Forearm->wrist and hand)
I'm not really experienced in the rigging part of the blender and this problem has made me frustrated.
PLZ HELP
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: This looks like an issue with weights.  We'd need to see the file.  I first would double check that the forearm bone has "deform" enabled in properties/bone/deform.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=k0xKPLdE" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/k0xKPLdE/)

Comment: sorry it was 3 in the morning and I had to sleep

Comment: I've added the link to your Blend file into your question.

Comment: @JohnEason thanks!

Comment: @Nathan I also tried turning on deform for the forearm bone and nothing changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you see this bone has too much influence on the forearm, you need to correct by weight painting or simply try a *Weights > Assign Automatic from Bones*:

[image]

After the operation:

[image]

Comment: It worked! Thanks