# How can i add and parent a new bone to an already rigged character?

Tags: rigging, armature

Normally, i'd find this quite simple. However, i dont want to redo my weight painting. So, if I had a new bone for my characters wrist. I will have to re-parent the character to the armature with automatic weights in order to get this new wrist bone to affect the character. But i dont want to re-do the weight painting for the rest of the character. Is there a work around for this?

Comment: Ttry a Weights > Assign Automatic from Bones, see my answer here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/301284/i-have-problem-rigging-this-arm/301305#301305